# Does iOS In-App-Purchase cancellation reflect on NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, auto-renewing, receipt-validation

Let's say an iOS user purchases an auto renewal subscription. I am aware that `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` shows some kind of digital receipt I can use to verify the purchase and the continuation of the subscription.

Then after some point the user cancels the subscription.

**Questions**:

When user cancels the subscription,

1. Does `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` reflect that cancellation right away?

I'm skeptical in this regard because `NSBundle.mainBundle()` is used to pull up what's stored locally in the app. If the user cancels the subscription by going to the OS' settings, and that will send some type of notification to Apple Server, then Apple Server should notify the app somehow.

2. If somehow `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` reflects the cancellation right away. How does Apple do it? Or is it up to me to implement a protocol to get the cancellation info?
3. If, in fact, I do need to run a protocol, do other apps run it every time the app is launched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user doesn't cancel the subscription as such. They turn off the renewal, so the subscription will not renew at the completion of the current period.  If the auto renewal was still enabled then a new in-app purchase would be added to the receipt for the next period, but this will now not occur, so your app should determine that there isn't a currently active subscription and remove access to the content/features as appropriate.

Apple can cancel a subscription at the request of the user. In this case the `cancellation_date` field of the in-app purchase receipt item will have a value and your app should treat it as if the purchase was never made.

Your app should periodically (and at least at every launch) refresh the application receipt and verify the currently active subscriptions.

Comment: So are you saying, assuming the user cancelled the auto renewal subscription, when I refresh my receipt, NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL will show nil?

Comment: The user can't cancel the subscription. If they ask Apple to cancel the subscription then the receipt is updated so that the relevant in-app purchase item in the receipt has a `cancellation_date`. `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` always has a value even without inapp purchases since the receipt contains the details of the app purchase itself (even if it is free)

Comment: I can confirm that if the user cancels the subscription the receipt is always there

Comment: My understanding is that when the user decides to no longer continue autorenewable subscription, NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL will still show something, but when the expires_date of the most recent subscription comes, the receipt won't add another transaction continuing the subscription. Is that what you are saying? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, that is correct. Once a subscription is purchased it can only be cancelled before the end of the period by Apple. If the user cancels the renewal then that takes effect at the end of the current period; in that case another period is. It added to the receipt as you say